# GEE - Sentinel 1 - Instrument Mode 'SM' doesn't return any results

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I am trying to visualize some Sentinel 1 strip maps from Tristan da Cunha in GEE (which I know exist based on scihub) - but my code doesnt return them. Any suggestions?

```
<  // Filter the collection - VV only depending on geometry and date
var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'SM'))
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-07-31')
    .select(['VV']);
print(s1);


//visualisation parameters!  
 var viz = {
 bands: ['VV'],
  min: -40.0,
  max: -10,
};


// display each image in collection
function addImage(s1) { 
  var id = s1.id;
  var scene = ee.Image(s1.id);
  Map.addLayer(scene, viz, id);
  Map.centerObject(geometry,6);
}


// use map on client-side
s1.evaluate(function(s1) {  
  s1.features.map(addImage);
});>
```

Answer (score 1):

EE doesn't ingested GRD SM because the noise removal operator in the S1 toolbox does not support the SM mode:
https://github.com/senbox-org/s1tbx/blob/master/s1tbx-op-calibration/src/main/java/org/esa/s1tbx/calibration/gpf/RemoveGRDBorderNoiseOp.java